# Need help/suggestions on android play music synchronously on multiple devices

Tags: android, performance

I am working on the android app that should be play music synchronously on multiple android devices like galaxy s4's group play how can I achieve this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the demo project on github.
Here's [a link](https://github.com/bryan-y88/Musics_Around)!
this demo project play music synchronously on multiple android devices.
thanks [Bryan.](https://github.com/bryan-y88)

Comment: Thanks It's Perfect Demo
I Want to play music synchronously on multiple devices Using **Wi-fi Hotspot** And For That I'm Using **NanoHTTPD**  

But I'm Succeeded in Streaming Audio to Wi-Fi Hotspot IP address but At Receiver Side 
It's not Working Its show me **Media I/O Exception**
Can You Help Me Thanks

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Comment: Hello @AZ_, can you achieve the task? I am planning to do something similar! Can you share your!